# How to dump json files into mongodb?

Tags: python, json, mongodb

I have few hundred JSON files which I want to insert into mongo database. I have written this code but it's not working. I'm getting error as

```
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

The code is below:

```
import glob
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient('localhost',27017)
path = '/home/rahul/Desktop/*.json'
files = glob.glob(path)
db = client.helloworld
c = db.docs
for f in files:
    c.insert(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

`insert` takes arguments of dict format

```
for f in files:
    c.insert({"file_name":f})
```

Have a look at the [docs](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/tutorial.html#documents)

Comment: There are 100 files in which there can be spaces between the names of files. For instance, the file name can be of "Rahul Ranjan.json". How can I do this? I have written a script as well which is using mongoimport but it's inserting only those docs whose name are like "Rahul.json".

Comment: @Rahul in the script mentioned in the question files should contain filenames with both spaces and without spaces. There shouldn't be any problem inserting it into mongodb